# How to add path to system PATH for MSBuild?

Tags: windows-7, msbuild, system-paths

Even when I try to put the path to the containing folder of `MSBuild.exe` e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`, calling MSBuild from a command-line doesn't work.

How can I reach that?

Comment: How did you try to add it?

Comment: `set path=%path%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` should do. Or opening the Visual Studio Command Prompt from the start menu instead of the standard console.

Comment: I figure it out my mistake. It seems I have one extra space preceeding C:\ when adding to PATH; i.e. `(something before); C:\my\path`. It should be `(something before);C:\my\path\`

Comment: @NamGVU: You should probably post you solution as an answer and accept it so this question is marked as having an accepted answer.

Comment: @NamGVU: And now you only need to accept it, :p.

Comment: Haha, sorry for my missed. Done for now. Thanks again! @cic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out my mistake. It seems I have one extra space preceeding C:\ when adding to PATH; i.e. `(something before); C:\my\path`. It should be `(something before);C:\my\path`